# How to create idendical variables in MATLAB from an array of variable names?

Tags: string, matlab, for-loop, indexing

I have the following code in Matlab:

```
a = zeros(23,1)
b = zeros(23,1)
c = zeros(23,1)
```

How can I write it more compactly? I was looking for a solution that is something like this:

```
str = {'a','b','c'}
for i = str{i}
    i = zeros(23,1)
end
```

But I can't find a way to do it properly without an error message. Can someone help please?

Comment: The first one is good, no need to change it. You can also always do `d=zeros(23,3)` and index each of the second dimension.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can also use a `struct` if the variable name is important:

```matlab
str = {'a','b','c'};
data = struct
for ii = 1:numel(str)
    data.(str{ii}) = zeros(23,1);
end
```

The struct is more efficient than the table. You can now address `data.a`, `data.b`, etc.

But if the name is not useful, it's best to put your data into a cell array:

```matlab
N = 3;
data = cell(N,1);
for ii = 1:N
    data{ii} = zeros(23,1);
end
```

or simply:

```matlab
data = cell(3,1);
[data{:}] = deal(zeros(23,1));
```

Now you address your arrays as `data{1}`, `data{2}`, etc., and they're always easy to address in loops.

Comment: Structs aren't necessarily more efficient than tables... It depends what you're doing

Comment: @Wolfie: sure. But `A.field` is significantly faster if `A` is a struct than a table. A table is a user class, so indexing into it runs some M-file code. A struct is a built-in type. There's a Q&A somewhere on here where these two are timed.

Answer (score 5):

Here is a compact way using [`deal`](https://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/deal.html) :

```
[a, b, c] = deal(zeros(23,1));
```

Answer (score 3):

**What you're tempted to do is very bad practise**, but can be done like this

```
str = {'a','b','c'};
for ii = 1:numel(str)
    eval( [str{ii} ' = zeros(23,1)'] );
end
```

*Why is this bad practise?*

- Your code legibility has just gone way down, you can't clearly see where variables are declared.
- `eval` [should be avoided](https://blogs.mathworks.com/loren/2005/12/28/evading-eval/)

You could use `deal` to make things a bit nicer, but this doesn't use the array of variable names

```
[a, b, c] = deal( zeros(23, 1) );
```

Even better, it's likely you can optimise your code by using a matrix or table instead of separate 1D arrays. The table option means you can still use your variable name array, but you're not using `eval` for anything!

```
% Matrix
M = zeros( 23, 3 ); % Index each column as a/b/c using M(:,1) etc

% Table, index using T.a, T.b, T.c
T = array2table( zeros(23,3), 'VariableNames', {'a','b','c'} );
```